# Core Data mapping model

Tags: xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I' trying to make custom core data migration. I created a .xcmappingmodel, but when I try to compile the project I get an error:
[image: Error]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check the quoted strings in your model Fetchs.

Comment: There's a pretty clear error message there about a format string. Have you checked on that to make sure it's OK?